# What's a good design to show a freelancer's rate compared to min, avg and max?

Tags: pricing, price-range

As the title suggests, I need a good idea for a design to show a freelancer's rate and compare it to other freelancers min, average and maximum rate.

I would appreciate any suggestion to improve one of my ideas or a new better idea.
I like Glassdoor's approach and it's similar to my first idea with the bar.

My ideas:
[image]

Glassdoor:
[image]

Comment: I'd urge you to use the **modal** value -- it's best for things like rate comparisons.  The "average" (mean) is much less good because it's so responsive to outliers, and the median conveys nothing but spread.

Comment: @MMacD thanks for the suggestion, would you mind clarifying more of the importance of using the Modal value Vs. the Mean. If there is a link to an article it would be great or if you could give the pros and cons of such thing. Thanks.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer -it's long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design looks clear. Some ideas:

- As in the Glassdoor example, you could use an empty rectangle and fill it with your value (green color). This also encourages the message that there is empty space which is money the client is saving.
- Use only one color to bring focus: your color, green.
- Horizontal diagram: either display common values over the line and yours below or the other way round. (This might also work in the vertical diagram: left/right)
- Horizontal diagram: Remove extra space on the sides of the min/max handlers.
- Vertical diagram: The long width is not giving any extra information so keep it short enough to be understandable.
- I was not sure about filling with a subtle grey the distance from your salary to the average, possibly both could work.
- The typography: I didn't change this on the image but I think you could use a bolder one and a green color a bit darker.

[image]

Comment: **Great suggestions**. The reason I had the vertical design very wide is because I needed something to take more space, but you're right, if it didn't contain any useful information, then it is useless. I would have added the text inside boxes, but it would overlap when values are close to each other. I guess I'll stick with the the horizontal one. It also allows me to add another sliding handle for a client to propose a different rate. here's [an improved design](http://i.imgur.com/ypQROCI.png)

Comment: That *improved design* looks great to me. Text in black inside green handler is a good idea for readability.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.seci.info/stat/stat2_3.pdf  gives a nice depiction.

When doing rate comparison, people want to know how their rate compares with others.

The mean doesn't provide comparative information because it's extremely influenced by outliers.  Example: if 9 people make $10K p.a., and one makes $110K, the mean is $200K/10 = $20K.  Which most people would find useless for comparison purposes since most of the people in the sample make only half that!

Similarly with the median.  It represents the point at which half the values are above and the other half below *without regard to what the numbers are, or their "lumpiness"*. If we take the case where out of 100 people 50 get $10K p.a. and the other 50 all over $100K, will the median be useful for comparison?  Not very.

The mode, in contrast, is the "most popular" value.  Because it's the one with the greatest number of instances, comparisons are meaningful *even if* the range of values has more than one mode, as for example the salaries in a law office.  If you're being asked to accept $50K p.a. as an associate, and you know that the clerical staff get $35K, the associates get $75K, and the partners get $1M or more, you know that if you take the job you'll be underpaid by comparison with your peers.  Neither the mean nor the median can tell you that, but the mode can.

Comment: Good points, I agree with you on that, it makes sense. Thanks for your answer, I will come back to upvote your answer once I hit 15 reputation.